# Need to output the final count instead of one by one

Tags: python, list

I turned a given string into a list of words and then made a loop to count the number of 'to' contained in the list. However, it comes out as individual '1's but I need the answer to be the total word_count == 4 somehow.

```
Input words = ['to', 'split;', 'bill', 'to', 'lint', 'to', 'leads', 'to', 'suffer']

print(words)
word_count = 0
    
for target_word in words:
    if (target_word == 'to'):
       print(word_count + 1)
```

Output:

```
['to', 'split;', 'bill', 'to', 'lint', 'to', 'leads', 'to', 'suffer']
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Thanks to anyone for their help. I am in a different timezone and cannot contact my admin for help atm.

Comment: you want to count words in a text ?

Comment: You want `word_count += 1`, and then `print(word_count)` after the loop…?!

Comment: The f string at the top of the file has no effect. Did you mean to print it?

Comment: Pls ignore the f string it is from a previous part of the problem. Im supposed to loop over the list of words and test each word to see if it ==  target_word
and  then increment word_count by one if it does.
word_count== 4 has to be my answer. Im not sure how to get there...

Answer (score 2):

```
words = text.split()
print(words)
word_count = 0

for target_word in words:
    if (target_word == 'to'):
        word_count += 1
print(word_count)
```

An even simpler approach would be

```
print(words.count("to"))
```

If you want to get a summary of words, then:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(words)
print(c)
```

Comment: you are very welcome. @lnaomi if this solves your problem, feel free to mark the answer as a correct one :)

Comment: @jude if this answers your question, feel free to mark the answers as accepted